# MongoDB: sorting by $meta: "textScore" returns no results among documents generated from original $text search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB and Mongoose to make a website that has businesses and reviews. There is a text index on the reviews so that users can search for businesses based on the text in their corresponding reviews.

1. The results should be ordered by the average $meta: "textScore".
2. They should also be accompanied by a snippet from the review with the highest $meta: "textScore".

The problem comes in the second part of the search: some businesses seem to have no matching reviews.

My query is structured as follows:

1. Search the reviews with $text, group by business, and sort by average "textScore":

```
Review
    .aggregate([ 
      { $match: { $text: { $search: query } } },
      { $group: { _id: "$businessId", avgScore: { $avg: { $meta: "textScore" } } } },
      { $sort: { avgScore: -1 } }
    ])
```

2. In the callback for the first query, I find the corresponding businesses:

```
 Business
     .find( { id: { $in: resultIds } } )
```

3. In a final callback, I search for each business' best matching review:

```
Review.find({ 
      businessId: business.id, 
      $text: { $search: query }, 
      score: { $meta: "textScore" }
    })
    .sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
    .limit(1)
```

The first two steps work fine. The last step mostly works, but sometimes the lowest ranking businesses seem to have no matching reviews.

How can businesses that were generated by the original $text search then return no results for the later $text search?

**Edit: follow-up question**
Could I achieve the same query using Mongoose .populate()? I ran into a similar problem with the code below:

```
Business
    .find({ _id: { $in: searchResults} })
    .populate({
      path: "reviews",
      match: { $text: { $search: query } },
      select: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
      options: { sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }, limit: 1 }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `find` call, you need to provide `score: { $meta: "textScore" }` as a separate projection object parameter instead of including it in your query object:

```
Review.find({ 
      businessId: business.id, 
      $text: { $search: query }      
    }, {
      score: { $meta: "textScore" }
    })
    .sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
    .limit(1)
```